# Migrate list SharePoint 2003 to SP online

Tags: sharepoint-online, migration

I don't know anything about sharepoint before 2010 and a customer asks us to migrate list with attached documents from 2003 to online.

In 2010, i can use sharepoint client object model but for 2003, what can i do?
Are there an assembly like sharepoint.client.dll in SP 2003?

thanks

Comment: I'd say your best option is a third party tool. But I can't add that as answers since our community doesn't allow paid third party tools as answers :-)

Comment: There are no free tool to migrate or any script to develop?

Comment: None that I'm aware of, no...

Comment: Thanks for your help and wich tool can i use? i'll ask to my company to pay a license